# Option to cancel job by jobname not ID?

Tags: linux, job-control, torque

Is it possible to delete multiple jobs with the same name, instead of typing in each individual job number?

I do not want to use the `qdel -u username` option, as I have other jobs that I want to spare. It is +100 individual jobs so would rather not type in each jobnumber if there's a quicker option!

I found this option online;

```
qdel wc_jobname
```

But it returns the error,

> qdel: illegally formed job identifier: wc_jobname

Comment: Maybe it's possible to write a script which gets the jobnumbers and kills the jobs?

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare a script which takes the job name as an argument and which checks if exists... In case of existing it would delete that job... For example you can use this script as reference:

```
#!/bin/bash

#check processes in standby, which matches with our process name
ps T |grep $1 |grep -v 'grep' |grep -v $0 |awk '{print $1}' > /tmp/temp.txt

i=0
if [ $(cat /tmp/temp.txt |wc -l) -eq 0 ];
then
        echo "there are no jobs to kill"
else
#if there are jobs, kill and count them to know how many processes have been killed
while read pid
do
        kill -9 $pid
        i=$((i+1))
done < /tmp/temp.txt
#show how many jobs have been killed
echo "$i jobs killed"
fi
rm /tmp/temp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```bash
jobs -lr | grep -F something | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

`-l` lists the process-id

`-r` limits to running jobs

Answer (score 0):

[man killall:](https://linux.die.net/man/1/killall)

> killall sends a signal to all processes running any of the specified commands. If no signal name is specified, SIGTERM is sent.
>
> Signals can be specified either by name (e.g. -HUP or -SIGHUP ) or by number (e.g. -1) or by option -s.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `qdel [job_name]`.  If the job name is "analysis1" for example, you do `qdel analysis1`.  Sometimes you need to add a `-f` so `qdel -f analysis1`.